# Link tags doesn't works in content tag

Tags: html, anchor, hyperlink, placeholder

I need help about creating anchor tag inside the content tag. It works if I set the exact path like `<a id="loginLink" runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a>` . But is there a solution if I want to set dynamicaly created path through Session like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="registerLink" href='<%# Session["PreviousPage"] %>'>Register</a></li>
    </ul>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be work fine:

```
<a id="registerLink" href="<%= Session["PreviousPage"] %>">Register</a>
```

Comment: Yes it works. It also works with '<a id="registerLink" href="<%: Session["PreviousPage"] %>">Register</a>'